# Website that decode chess moves?

Tags: engines, analysis, learning, online-chess

I am a complete beginner and have started learning chess one month ago. I play online on lichess.com. I lose a lot of games which is understandable too.

Many people advised me that I should analyze my own games. I have came across number of online websites(also lichess inbuilt analyzer) that tells me what is the best move.

But I want to know why that specific move is the best move, what are advantages of playing "X" move in comparison with "Y" move etc.

In short is there a website/engine that decodes the chess moves from me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking if you were the author of https://decodechess.com, and posted here for self-promotion. "decode" isn't a common terminology here. What you're asking match exactly to the name of the site.

Ok. Please take a look at the site.
I personally don't use it as I found the analysis too simple/too naive. Maybe you'd think otherwise.

Comment: I am a mathematics student and this term is used a lot in mathematics. Maybe that;s why I used it. :p Thanks for suggestion. Have a good day ahead.

Comment: Having tested the site, I agree with the naive/simple part. It might give semi-decent results for simple tactics, but expectedly it won't help much with long term positional plans, etc.

Comment: ...worse still, in slightly more complicated positions it would decode you some minor irrelevant one to three move (or so) deep tactics, missing the main point.

Comment: @user1583209 The site implemented the old Chessmaster annotation style. It's like a re-make for the classic Chessmaster.

Comment: @user1583209 I'm sure the site uses simple engine techniques. Without machine learning, there's no chance an engine is able to work out plans.

Answer (score 1):

> Many people advised me that I should analyze my own games.

Good advise, but unfortunately impossible to do for a beginner.

> In short is there a website/engine that decodes the chess moves from me?

There is one (see the answer by SmallChess), however I am rather pessimistic about decoding done by computers.

As mentioned in my comments, for simple tactics, the site mentioned does a pretty decent job explaining the ideas behind the moves.

In less tactical/more equal positions, however in my experience, it will overload you with fairly irrelevant short term plans missing the long term idea behind it.

If you think you find this or similar sites useful, go for it. Personally I'd recommend to watch/read commented/annotated games (books, or youtube or chess24 or...) and if possible have a stronger player analyze games with you (perhaps join a chess club). IMO, can't beat human analysis of chess.

Comment: I would be thankful if you can recommend me some  books that have commented games. I mean books which explain the moves in detail. I googled it but I have not found anything useful yet as lot of books pop up.

Comment: I stopped buying chess books a long time ago, so can't recommend anything recent. The ones I have are not in English, so might not be useful to you either. Anyway, live (or non-live) video analysis of games  is everywhere on the internet and if done by good players, at least as good as books. As I write this I listen to Anish Giri and Peter Svidler, two of the very best players, commenting on the WC match live on chess24 (I am not associated with that website). You can watch the same broadcast later on as well.

Comment: I am also following WCC2018 on chess24. Thanks for the advice and taking time to write a reply. Have a good day!

Comment: @StammeringMathematician: The WCC2018 on chess24 might be a bit too high level for beginners, but they do have broadcasts for different levels. I believe the ones by Sopiko Guramishvili & Anna Rudolf might be more accessible for beginners.